# Issue about Using Struts2 Include Tag in Freemarker File 

Tags: macros, struts2, jsp-tags, freemarker, oscache

Here is my scene：

### 1、In action the variable id is declear like blow(TestAction.java):

```
… 
private Integer id;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
} 
…
```

---

### 2、Configuration in web.xml:

```
…
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
…
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>JSPSupportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
…
```

---

### 3、Called in freemarker file(test.ftl):

```
…
  <@s.include value="/invitation/inviter"/><#-- there is no variable id in this action -->
…
  <span>${id}<span>
…
```

---

### 4、Error message:

```
Error on line 63, column 61 in WEB-INF/ftl/invitation/ test.ftl
Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression id!0 is instead a freemarker.ext.beans.ArrayModel
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${id} [on line 63, column 59 in WEB-INF/ftl/invitation/test.ftl]
in user-directive page [on line 1, column 1 in WEB-INF/ftl/invitation/ test.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.NonStringException: Error on line 63, column 61 in WEB-INF/ftl/invitation/ test.ftl
Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression id!0 is instead a freemarker.ext.beans.ArrayModel
         at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:126)
         at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
         at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
         at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
```

---

is there angthing wrong with my code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
the num variable setting code was added.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are trying to display the TestAction object not the ID.

Try doing this:

---

```
${testAction.id}
```

or in your current case this:

```
${id.id}
```

---

That is equivalent to:

```
(new TestAction()).getId()
```

or

```
existingTestAction.getId()
```

---

Taka look at this answer here: [Getting template text from FreeMarker in Struts2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985373/getting-template-text-from-freemarker-in-struts2-app)

And this link: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/using-freemarker-templates.html

It is hard to tell what model data you are putting into your Action since you didn't post the whole action class.